# Even though not special characters some of the words not displaying in PHP

Tags: php, json, sql-server, xampp

I have this weird problem , that i am retrieving data from SQL Server through Xammp server and showing in PHP by the browser ( through json output) , so some of the strings I want to show in browser has description like for example

```
"**Delightfully warmingour butterysweet tart crusts are filled with delicious fillings Try the lemontart for a slice of sweet and tangy flavour**"
```

and another example

```
" **Richwarm and homemadeour chocolate brownie has a fudgy inside and a crisp chocolaty outside  served with a scoop of VANILLA ICE CREAM Rs 430**"
```

doesn't show in the browser when i retrieve from database through PHP, as you can see there are no special characters ( except the comma ",") but the even with the "," it shows in some of the descriptions but specifically the above two examples not showing in the browser.

I don't understand why and its very weird, can anyone help me with this issue , help will be highly appreciated with this regard,

The PHP code as below:

```
<?php
    //require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/connectionInfoTest.php');
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/connectionInfoTestNew.php');

{
    //Set up our connection
    $connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    $connectionInfo->GetConnection();

    if (!$connectionInfo->conn) {
        //Connection failed
        echo 'No Connection';
    } else {

        $query = " SELECT i.itemid as fir_ID,i.name as fir_name,
                    i.code, i.itemdescription,i.unitprice,i.isservicecharge,
                    i.costprice,i.itemgroupid,i.image,c2.name as sec_name 
                    FROM vw_app_item i 
                        inner join itemlayer1 c1 on i.itemlayer1id = c1.itemlayer1id 
                        inner join itemlayer2 c2 on i.itemlayer2id=c2.itemlayer2id 
                    WHERE c2.name in ('ICED TEA','BLACK TEA','MOCKKTAIL',
                                        'SPARKLING TEA','T-SHAKES','SMOOTHIE',
                                        'WATTE','BRUSCHETTA','BRUSCHETTA','CREPE',
                                        'BURGER','DESSERT','ICE CREAM',
                                        'PIZZA','TOASTIE','WAFFLE','WRAP','TACO') 
                    order by c1.name,c2.name";  // query to check the all the categories


        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($connectionInfo->conn, $query);

        if (!$stmt)
        {
            //Query failed
            echo 'Query failed';
        } else {
            $contacts = array(); //Create an array to hold all of the contacts
            //Query successful, begin putting each contact into an array of contacts

            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) //While there are still contacts
            {
                //Create an associative array to hold the current contact
                //the names must match exactly the property names in the contact class in our C# code.
                $contact= array("ID" => $row['fir_ID'],
                                 "Category" => $row['sec_name'],
                                 "Name" => $row['fir_name'],
                                 "Code" => $row['code'],
                                 "Description" => $row['itemdescription'],
                                 "Price" => $row['unitprice'],
                                 "isservicecharge" => $row['isservicecharge'],
                                 "CostPrice" => $row['costprice'],
                                 "Date" => $row['itemgroupid'],                              
                                 "Image" => base64_encode($row['image'])                                                                                                 
                                 );                                  
                //Add the contact to the contacts array
                array_push($contacts, $contact);
            }

            //Echo out the contacts array in JSON format
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            $output = ['Resturent' => $contacts];
            echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How are you displaying the data? Check for any javascript errors.

Comment: Are you sure you are fetching correctly? Difficult to help if we cant see any code...

Comment: could you be more specific with the code. so everyone can understand easily.

Comment: sorry about insufficient information, I have edited my question with the existing php code i am having, Thank you all in-advance for your support

Comment: Could you post information about columns types (varchar, nvarchar, text, collation, ..)? Also could you put print_r($row, true); inside the while loop and show the output for these strings? Thanks.

Comment: "doesn't show in the browser"...do other fields display from the same row? Please show how you display the data in the browser. Have you checked to see if the values are present in the raw JSON? There is much more debugging you can do / info you can give us to narrow down where exactly in the process the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue generated from the blank spaces with in the item source , as far as the data base concern the data in the database should be stored without blank spaces in the middle